# One PHP SQL record forced to be on a specific place in the outcome list

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL table; it's not so super long so I sort it with RAND in a while loop.

Now I want a specific record to always be at (for example) the 4th place in the list created with the PHP query.

So the outcome must be a list where the first 3 must be selected with RAND, the 4 must always be a specific record and after that the results must be again ordered with RAND

I can add extra columns in the table to make this work.

Is it possible?

Ok here is what I've tried:

I have a database table:

```
+----+---------+
| id |  cars   |
+----+---------+
| z  | Opel    |
| z  | Audi    |
| a  | VW      |
| z  | Ford    |
| c  | Skoda   |
| z  | Renault |
+----+---------+
```

I want the VW on place 1 after that a random car and after that the Skoda and after that the rest.

But

```
ORDER BY id, RAND()
```

Output VW, Skoda, and the rest

I've also tried:

```
ORDER BY CASE
  WHEN id = 'a' THEN id
  WHEN id = 'b' THEN id
  WHEN id = 'c' THEN id
  WHEN id = 'z' THEN RAND()
END DESC
```

But the result is the same it walks over b because there is no.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest showing us what you've tried so far. A key element is to know how you select the 'special' record to be in position 4.

Comment: If your questions is "Is it possible?" the answer is YES. Anything is possible in software.  as BigScar says show us more.

Comment: A Beat, Thanks for the better edit!